# How to parse this json into apex list of strings containing SpecialName values?

Tags: apex, json, parser, jsongenerator

Hey fellow salesforcers,

Im a bit stuck parsing specific values from a json into an apex List `stringList`

Using apex (with or without using Json2Apex),  how can we parse the following JSON structure to construct a List that contains all of the `SpecialName` *values*?

Im hoping to use apex to parse the json into a `List<String> stringList` that i expect to contain all the `SpecialNames` , for example: {'valueOfInterest1','valueOfInterest2','valueOfInterest3',''... etc} however my `stringList` debugs to null

**My JSON ( `response` variable ) :** (with or without surrounding [])

```
{
  "size" : 25,
  "totalSize" : 25,
  "done" : true,
  "queryLocator" : null,
  "entityTypeName" : "someEntityType",
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/1"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest1"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/2"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest2"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/3"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest3"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/4"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest4"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/5"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest5"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/6"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest6"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/7"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest7"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/8"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest8"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/9"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest9"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/10"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest10"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/11"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest11"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/12"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest12"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/13"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest13"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/14"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest14"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/15"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest15"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/16"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest16"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/17"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest17"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/18"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest18"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/19"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest19"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/20"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest20"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/21"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest21"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/22"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest22"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/23"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest23"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/24"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest24"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "someEntityType",
      "url" : "/some/path/25"
    },
    "SpecialName" : "valueOfInterest25"
  } ]
}
```

**Attempt:**
Trying to follow similar pattern to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/201411/10073 by manually constructing the apex class, (not using json2apex):

```
public class MyPayload { 
    public class Result {     
            public final String SpecialName;
        }
}
```

**Problem:** i get a null list of strings when i inspect `stringList`

```
List<String> stringList = new List<String>();
List<MyPayload.Result> results = (List<MyPayload.Result>)JSON.deserialize(
    response, List<MyPayload.Result>.class
);
for (MyPayload.Result result : results)
{
    stringList.add(result.SpecialName);
}
```

i must be parsing this incorrectly.  Where am i going wrong and how do i populate `stringList` with all SpecialName values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, only change needed would be with construction of the wrapper structure.

In this case, the `type` attribute in `attributes` json string is a reserved character in apex, workaround to get a simpler structure with json2apex is to replace `type` with `type_x` or something like that.

Manually constructing the wrapper or using json to apex would give an apex class as below:

```java
public with sharing class PayloadHelper {

    public class MyPayload {
        public Integer size {get;set;}
        public Integer totalSize {get;set;}
        public Boolean done {get;set;}
        public Object queryLocator {get;set;}
        public String entityTypeName {get;set;}
        public List<Records> records {get;set;}
    }
    public class Attributes {
        // use the modified reserved keyword as property
        public String type_x {get;set;}
        public String url {get;set;}
    }
    public class Records {
        public Attributes attributes {get;set;}
        public String SpecialName {get;set;}
    }
    public static MyPayload parse(String json) {
        // modify the reserved keyword
        String modifiedJsonString  = json.replace('"type"', '"type_x"');
        return (MyPayload) System.JSON.deserialize(modifiedJsonString, MyPayload.class);
    }
}
```

Now the actual logic would look as below:

```java
String jsonString = '{ your JSON in here }';
PayloadHelper.MyPayload objParsedWrapper = PayloadHelper.parse(jsonString);
List<String> stringList = new List<String>();
for(PayloadHelper.Records records: objParsedWrapper.records) {
    stringList.add(records.SpecialName);
}
```

Basically it iterates over the response to collect the desired data would output:

> DEBUG|(valueOfInterest1, valueOfInterest2, valueOfInterest3, valueOfInterest4, valueOfInterest5, valueOfInterest6, valueOfInterest7, valueOfInterest8, valueOfInterest9, valueOfInterest10, ...)

Comment: Nice one, Raul! 